# pandas: complex grouping and nests

Tags: pandas, grouping, nested

Here is a sample data set. Assume that there are many other records and many many more customer records.

```
 customers = ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
 level = [10,15,30,49,12,15,49,9, 22, 49]
 cars = ['bmw','audi','vw','mercedes','bmw','bmw','audi','audi', 'bmw', 'audi']
 df = pd.DataFrame({'customers' : customers, 'levels' : level, 'cars': cars})
```

I am trying to count:

- The # of customers that have 1 car with a level 0-10
- The # of customers that have 2 cars with a level 0-10
- The # of customers that have 3 cars with a level 0-10
- The # of customers that have 1 car with a level 10-20
- The # of customers that have 2 cars with a level 10-20
- The # of customers that have 3 cars with a level 10-20
- Etc. etc.

This would seem to involved nested group and then counts at one level of the grouping, but I am getting stuck. Maybe there is work around with just using a pivot table with the aggregate function as count

Answer (score 1):

No promises that this is the slickest way, but I think you can get where you want to go with two groupbys, and a `cut` to get the levels:

```
df["lev"] = pd.cut(df.levels, bins=range(0,100,10), right=False)
dc = df.groupby(["customers", "lev"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
dfinal = dc.groupby(["lev", "count"]).size()
```

produces

```
>>> dfinal
lev       count
[0, 10)   1        1
[10, 20)  2        2
[20, 30)  1        1
[30, 40)  1        1
[40, 50)  1        3
dtype: int64
```

---

Step-by-step, if we add level bins:

```
>>> df["lev"] = pd.cut(df.levels, bins=range(0,100,10), right=False)
>>> df
       cars customers  levels       lev
0       bmw         a      10  [10, 20)
1      audi         a      15  [10, 20)
2        vw         a      30  [30, 40)
3  mercedes         a      49  [40, 50)
4       bmw         b      12  [10, 20)
5       bmw         b      15  [10, 20)
6      audi         b      49  [40, 50)
7      audi         c       9   [0, 10)
8       bmw         c      22  [20, 30)
9      audi         c      49  [40, 50)
```

Then we can group on `customers` and `lev` to figure out how many cars there are in each group:

```
>>> dc = df.groupby(["customers", "lev"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
>>> dc
  customers       lev  count
0         a  [10, 20)      2
1         a  [30, 40)      1
2         a  [40, 50)      1
3         b  [10, 20)      2
4         b  [40, 50)      1
5         c   [0, 10)      1
6         c  [20, 30)      1
7         c  [40, 50)      1
```

And from this we can count how many customers there are of a certain lev/count pair:

```
>>> dfinal = dc.groupby(["lev", "count"])["customers"].size()
>>> dfinal
lev       count
[0, 10)   1        1
[10, 20)  2        2
[20, 30)  1        1
[30, 40)  1        1
[40, 50)  1        3
dtype: int64
```